# glib installation :32bit Glib library installation on x86_64bit ( 64bit ) machine

Tags: installation, glib, libtool, systemtap

I have downloaded glib 2.56 sources from here:

https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.56/

And then i am trying to build & install 32-bit glib library on 64-bit x86_64 platform using following commands:-

```
../configure CC='/local/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0p2/bin/gcc -m32' CXX='/local/common/data/gcc/v6.3.0p2/bin/g++ -m32' CFLAGS='-fPIC -O2' CXXFLAGS='-fPIC -O2' LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/local/common/data/gcc/v6.3.0p2/lib LDFLAGS=-m32 --enable-static=yes --prefix=/home/gout/source_glib/32bit_glib/glib-2.56.1/glib_32bit --enable-libmount=no PYTHON=/local/common/data/python/v2.7.6/bin/python --with-pcre=/home/gout/pcre_32bit/pcre-8.20/pcre_install

make
make install
```

While building code (using 'make' command). I am hitting following issue:-

```
/local/common/pkgsData/gcc-v6.3.0p2/Linux/RHEL6.0-2013-x86_64/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `.libs/glib_probes.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

I found that file 'glib_probes.' is getting created with 64bit architecture.

```
[gout@il-gout glib]$ file .libs/glib_probes.o
.libs/glib_probes.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Above particular file is getting created by command :-

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile --silent --tag=CC dtrace -G -s ../../glib/glib_probes.d -o glib_probes.lo
```

Rule where we are running above command from glib source is :-

```
glib_probes.lo: glib_probes.d
    $(AM_V_GEN) $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(AM_V_lt) --tag=CC $(DTRACE) -G -s $< -o $@
```

variable `LIBTOOL` points to `libtool` script which got created after running ./configure script. I have mentioned `CC= '/local/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0p2/bin/gcc -m32'` to configure script, Still this particular file `glib_probes.o` is getting created with 64 bit architecture.. Not sure whats wrong in creating glib library.

I verified that all other files were created with 32-bit architecture except above file... Please help me in fixing this issue. This issue leads to issue failing creating `libglib-2.0.la`

```
  CCLD     libglib-2.0.la
/local/common/data/gcc-v6.3.0p2/Linux/RHEL6.0-2013-x86_64/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `.libs/glib_probes.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Answer (score 2):

The Meson build script that glib uses does not pass down the `CC` setting specified at configure time. Systemtap's `dtrace` tool uses `CC` from the environment, so you could call make like this:

```
CC="/local/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0p2/bin/gcc -m32" make
```

Alternatively, you can disable those probes at configure time using `--disable-dtrace` if you do not need them.

Comment: BTW, I used --disable-dtrace, And able to build glib library..Not sure whether my application needs probes stuff. After creating glib library. When i try to use that library in my application i am facing : undefined symbol: pthread_key_create.

Comment: No, you would have to set `CC` during the invocation of `make`. It is unlikely that you will need probes, they are only for debugging.

Comment: Florian, Our regressions are failing with trance errors. Not sure if its because of skip building probes stuff.. I want to include probes stuff while creating build. Setting up environment variable and triggering make should work right ? I.e setenv CC '/local/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0p2/bin/gcc -m32' then after 'make'

Comment: `setenv` sounds like csh, I'm not familiar with that. But it ought to work. Maybe the generated makefiles do something funny though. If everything fails, you could introduce a wrapper script for `gcc` and put that on the `PATH`.